# Angular 13 with VS 2022

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2022

I upgraded my project from angular 13 with VS 2019 to angular 13 with VS 2022 after a code conversation I got the below error while running the application, any help appreciated.

**runtime.js:1** Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

**polyfills.js:1** Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

**vendor.js:1** Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

**main.js:1** Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".

Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

:44395/manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
browserLink:21

Comment: Create a new project in Visual Studio 2022 and see what differences there are between the projects.

Comment: Thanks for you reply MegaMan, new project working fine, but old one is not,

Comment: Hmmm Maybe port over the components one by one and at least, you will have a working footprint.